# Meta Reduction in Fiat Shamir Transformation

Tags: fiat-shamir, reduction

What is meant by meta reduction? What does it achieve and how is it different from the normal reduction technique?

Comment: There's just way too much context missing here. I mean I can *guess* which paper you're talking about, but that's asking a bit much.

Comment: @Maeher You meant to say: "Could you please add context to this question, for instance by indicating the paper?".

Comment: I'm fairly certain that I said exactly what I meant to say, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

pls refer to this paper which I'm studying: On the Impossibility of Tight Cryptographic Reductions.

Meta reduction is the reduction of a reduction! We can use it to rule out some impossibile results of security proof. For example, to prove that there is no tight reduction exists for a signature scheme, we can build a meta reduction to break the underlying security assumption directly if such tight reducition exists.